# i am making a function and a loop and getting a list index out of range error

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I am trying to make a function that removes any item that is the same as the one next to it.
I have the code bellow and i am getting a list index out of range error.
If you can help that will be amazing,
Thank You.

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    chars = list(iterable)
    for i in range(len(chars)):
        if i > 0:
            if chars[i] == chars[i-1]:
                chars.remove(chars[i])
    return chars
```

Comment: That's bound to happen. The moment you remove an element from `chars`, your loop will inevitably hit an index out of bounds, because `chars` isn't as long anymore.

Comment: Are you trying to make sure you whole list in unique?  Try chars = set(iterable)

Comment: try looping backwards

Comment: @jayveesea what do you mean loop backwards and can u show me some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the order of your `for` loop, starting at the next to last item, you won't mess up the range of your loop as you drop items from the list you are working on.

So in your case start at `len(chars)-2` and go to `-1` (to include 0) and step `-1` like this: `for i in range(len(chars)-2,-1,-1)` and remove the `i+1` item if needed.

Also, the `[remove(x)][1]` method will remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to the `x`, so in this case `pop([i])` should be used to ensure the targeted duplicate is removed.

```py
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    chars = list(iterable)
    for i in range(len(chars)-2,-1,-1):
        if chars[i] == chars[i+1]:
            #print('removing ' + chars[i+1])
            chars.pop(i+1)
        print(chars)
    return chars

out = unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBBX')
print(out)
```

returns:
`['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'X']`

Comment: thank you that almost works but if out = unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') it will return ['C', 'D', 'A', 'B'] and i need it to return ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']

Comment: btw, I think using the `remove` method removes all of those items, so now using `pop`.